# Postgres int4range upper bound unexpected value

Tags: postgresql, range, upperbound

Using PostgreSQL 9.4:

```
SELECT x, lower(x), upper(x) FROM (SELECT '[1,2]'::numrange x) q;
> [1,2] | 1 | 2      -- looks OK

SELECT x, lower(x), upper(x) FROM (SELECT '[1,2]'::int4range x) q;
> [1,3) | 1 | >>3<<  -- this is unexpected
```

Let's check further:

```
SELECT x, lower(x), upper(x) FROM (SELECT '[1,3)'::numrange x) q1;
> [1,3) | 1 | 3      -- looks OK

SELECT x, lower(x), upper(x) FROM (SELECT '[1,3]'::numrange x) q1;
> [1,3] | 1 | 3      -- looks OK
```

From pg documentation:

> upper(anyrange) | range's element type | upper bound of range | upper(numrange(1.1,2.2)) | 2.2

While `3` technically is an upper bound of the integer range `[1,3) ∩ ℕ = {1, 2}`, so are all natural numbers ≥ 2. I would expect the `upper` function returns the *supremum* (least upper bound) of the range.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

This happens because `int4range` is a [discrete range](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DISCRETE). Such ranges always automatically converted to their canonical representation in order to be able to test equivalence, f.ex.:

```
SELECT '[4,8]'::int4range = '(3,9)'::int4range
```

> The built-in range types `int4range`, `int8range`, and `daterange` all use a canonical form that includes the lower bound and excludes the upper bound; that is, `[)`. User-defined range types can use other conventions, however.

Comment: Yes, they are converted to the canonical form. And the range [1,2] is exactly the same a [1,3) in N. But 3 in the sup. of neither.

Comment: @FireBiker yes, 3 is not the supremum, but it is the upper bound (by PostgreSQL's definition) of `[1,3)`. You can use the `upper_inc()` to detect, if it's inclusive or not. I think it's because this way the functions are consistent (i.e. both `upper('[1,3)'::int4range)` and `upper('[1,3)'::numrange)` will give `3`) -- note that supremum can be referred as the *least upper bound*, while PostgreSQL only uses the term *upper bound*

Answer (score 1):

The canonical form of the closed range `[1,2]` is the half-open (or half-closed) range `[1,3)`. The function upper() returns the upper bound of the canonical form.

```
select upper(int4range(1, 2, '[]'));  -- Canonical form is '[1,3)'
--
3
```

That range doesn't contain the value 3.

```
select int4range(1, 2, '[]') @> 3;
--
f
```

> The built-in range types int4range, int8range, and daterange all use a
> canonical form that includes the lower bound and excludes the upper
> bound; that is, [). User-defined range types can use other
> conventions, however.

[Source: PostgreSQL discrete range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DISCRETE)

There's a different function to call if you need to know whether the value returned by upper() is inclusive.

```
select upper_inc(int4range(1, 2, '[]'));
--
f
```